# Image upload routing issue using laravel and vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to upload image but getting the error `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404`

Here is my code

```
<input type="file" id="file" class="form-control-file" v-on:change="onFileChange">

  methods:{
    goToLogin(){
      this.upload();
    },
    onFileChange(e){
      console.log('onFileChange');
      let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if(!files.length){
        return;
      }
      this.createImage(files[0]);
    },
    createImage(file){
      console.log('createImage');
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let vm = this;
      reader.onload = (e) =>{
        vm.image = e.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
    upload(){
      console.log('upload image= '+this.image);
      axios.post('/storage/images',{image: this.image}).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      });
    }
  }


public function saveImage(Request $request){
   $image = $request->file('image');
   $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $path = public_path('images/' . $filename);
   $user->image = $filename;
  $user->save();
}
```

In upload method i am getting data in image but issue is within '/storage/images'. Can anybody please help me to fix it.

Comment: Can you show your laravel controller code and please try make FormData object instead if {image: this.image}

Comment: @CaShiS please check the routes now

Comment: Where is you route '/storage/images' ? You dont have routing for this, so how can you upload image? You must create routing then in controller you can save image on specify directory

Comment: Yes i know but i don't know how to do it. Can you give me reference link?

Comment: Here you have code for getting image, resize and save with laravel controller https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-image-upload-and-resize?page=1

Comment: Thanks.. let me try

Comment: @CaShiS.. i am getting "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null". Can you check the controller code ? What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Probably you dont import this [library](https://github.com/Intervention/image)  it is very usefull with saving images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154767/discussion-between-cashis-and-hitendra).